# Exception: Null check operator used on a null value Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[Update]: This error is caused by [ScreenUtil package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil). I downgraded the package to 5.0.0 and now the error is gone.
If anyone can come up with a solution for the latest version of the package, then please answer.

I know that this exception occurs when! bang operator is used on a null value. I checked my code thoroughly but I don't find what was causing the error.

This error occurs when I log out and try to navigate to the SignUp screen from the Login Screen, but it works fine when I restart the application.

Logout -> LoginScreen -> Signup Screen ( Null check operator used on null value error )
Restart -> LoginScreen -> Signup Screen ( Screen is displayed without any error )

I also tried removing codes that are using! , but the error stays the same.

**Below is the Signup Screen Code:**

```
class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
bool _obscureText = true;
void _toggle() {
setState(() {
  _obscureText = !_obscureText;
});
}

//Checks If Username Already Exists
Future<bool> usernameCheck(String username) async {
final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('usernames')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: username)
    .get();
 return result.docs.isEmpty;
}

bool isLoading = false;

final snackBar = SnackBar(
behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 680.h, left: 50.w, right: 50.w),
content: const Text(
  'Username should have atleast 6 characters and less than 12 characters',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
 ),
);
final snackBar2 = SnackBar(
behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 680.h, left: 50.w, right: 50.w),
content: const Text(
  'Username is already taken',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
 ),
);

final TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _userNameTextController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);

CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
CollectionReference usernames =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('usernames');
CollectionReference banners =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('banners');

return Container(
  ........
  ),
  child: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ..........
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, right: 25.w),
                  child: reusableTextField(
                    'Enter Username',
                    Icons.person_outline,
                    false,
                    _userNameTextController,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.h,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, right: 25.w),
                  child: reusableTextField(
                    'Enter Email id',
                    Icons.email_outlined,
                    false,
                    _emailTextController,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.h,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, right: 25.w),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _passwordTextController,
                    obscureText: _obscureText,
                    enableSuggestions: !_obscureText,
                    autocorrect: !_obscureText,
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.lock_outline,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                      labelText: "Enter Password",
                      labelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: InkWell(
                        onTap: _toggle,
                        child: Icon(
                          _obscureText
                              ? FontAwesomeIcons.eye
                              : FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                          size: 15.sp,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                      fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.r),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: _obscureText
                        ? TextInputType.visiblePassword
                        : TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.h,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.w, right: 30.w),
                  child: isLoading
                      ? Container(
                          height: 50.h,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.h, 0, 20.h),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.r),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.sp),
                            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple,
                            ),
                          ))
                      : signButton(context, false, () async {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = true;
                          });

                          if (_userNameTextController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                              _userNameTextController.text.length < 12 &&
                              _userNameTextController.text.length > 5) {
                            final valid = await usernameCheck(
                                _userNameTextController.text);
                            if (valid) {
                              await authService
                                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                _emailTextController.text,
                                _passwordTextController.text,
                              )
                                  .then(
                                (value) {
                                  final User? user =
                                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                                  final uid = user?.uid;

                                  usernames.doc(uid).set(
                                    {
                                      'id': _userNameTextController.text,
                                    },
                                  );
                                  banners.doc(uid).set(
                                    {
                                     ......
                                    },
                                  );
                                  users.doc(uid).set(
                                    {
                                      ........
                                    },
                                  ).then((value) async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isLoading = false;
                                    });
                                    await Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const HomeScreen(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                                },
                              ).catchError(
                                (
                                  error,
                                ) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = false;
                                  });
                                  print('${error.message}');
                                  return null;
                                },
                              );
                            } else if (!valid) {
                              setState(() {
                                isLoading = false;
                              });
                              return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                  .showSnackBar(snackBar2);
                            }
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = false;
                            });
                            return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                          }
                        }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.h,
        ),
        logInOption(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

Row logInOption() {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Already have an account? ',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Text(
        'Log In Instead',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

**Code for the reusable text Field widget and sign button that I have used above:**

```
TextFormField reusableTextField(
String text,
IconData icon,
bool isPasswordType,
TextEditingController controller,
) {
return TextFormField(
controller: controller,
obscureText: isPasswordType,
enableSuggestions: !isPasswordType,
autocorrect: !isPasswordType,
cursorColor: Colors.black,
style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
),
decoration: InputDecoration(
  prefixIcon: Icon(
    icon,
    color: Colors.black87,
  ),
  labelText: text,
  labelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
  ),
  filled: true,
  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
  fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.r),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      width: 0,
      style: BorderStyle.none,
    ),
  ),
  ),
  keyboardType: isPasswordType
    ? TextInputType.visiblePassword
    : TextInputType.emailAddress,
  );
  }



Container signButton(BuildContext context, bool isLogin, Function onTap) {
return Container(
height: 50.h,
width: double.infinity,
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.h, 0, 20.h),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.r),
),
child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    onTap();
  },
  child: Text(
    isLogin ? 'LOG IN' : 'SIGN UP',
    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 18.sp,
    ),
  ),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.5);
      }
      return Colors.deepPurple;
    }),
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
      RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.r),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
);
}
```

ERROR:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was MaterialApp    lib\main.dart:23

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Element.widget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3203
#1      StatelessElement.widget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4824
#2      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart:229
#3      debugCheckHasMediaQuery
package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart:245
#4      MediaQuery.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/media_query.dart:859
#5      ScreenUtil.screenHeight
package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:74
#6      ScreenUtil.scaleHeight
package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:92
#7      ScreenUtil.setHeight
package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:113
#8      SizeExtension.h
package:flutter_screenutil/size_extension.dart:8
#9      new _SignupScreenState 
(package:quiz_app/screens/login%20signup/signup_screen.dart:78:41)
#10     SignupScreen.createState 
(package:quiz_app/screens/login%20signup/signup_screen.dart:19:39)
#11     new StatefulElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4842
#12     StatefulWidget.createElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:770
...     Normal element mounting (171 frames)
#183    Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3790
#184    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6422
#185    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3540
#186    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5845
#187    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6445
#188    Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3501
#189    ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4780
#190    StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4928
```

**My Main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<AuthService>(
      create: (_) => AuthService(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<TotalScore>(
      create: (_) => TotalScore(),
    ),
  ],
  child: const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ),
),
);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
),
);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
return ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(392.72727272727275, 807.2727272727273),
  minTextAdapt: true,
  builder: () => MaterialApp(
    builder: ((context, widget) {
      ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: widget!,
      );
    }),
    theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        button: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.sp),
      ),
      colorScheme:
          ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.white),
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
    home: Wrapper(),
  ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the error message and also indicate the line which causing the problem

Comment: @AhmadRaza I have just updated the question with error message and main.dart file.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is very clear. You get a null value, although you indicated with the nullsafety that there cannot be a null value. I think you need to remove the indication that you cannot have a null value in this place and figure out why you are getting it. Check the docs. https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: I just added an update to my question. The error is caused by the screenutil package. Downgrading the version to 5.0.0, resolved the error. If there is a solution to the latest version , then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It says you've got issues on particular line in `signup_screen.dart`

```
(package:quiz_app/screens/login%20signup/signup_screen.dart:78:41)
#10     SignupScreen.createState 
(package:quiz_app/screens/login%20signup/signup_screen.dart:19:39)
```

check `78`th character of `41` line
and `19`th character of `39`th line